# Error Node.insertBefore: Argument 1 is not an object. , for drag and drop on newly created todo item

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, draggable

i'm working on this todo app challenge and I'm getting the mentioned error for my drag and drop set up whenever a new todo is added. It works fine with the items that are already there, but as soon as a new todo item is created the code breaks.

```
const todoList = document.querySelector(".todos");
const draggables = document.querySelectorAll(".todos__item");
```

```
<ul class="todos">
        <li class="todos__item todo-style" draggable="true">
          <button
            class="todos__complete btn"
            aria-label="complete todo"
          ></button>
          <p class="todos__text">Create your own todos so you won't forget</p>

          <button class="todos__delete" aria-label="delete todo">
            <img
              class="todos__delete__img"
              src="assets/icon-cross.svg"
              alt="an icon with the symbol x that will allow you to delete the selected todo "
            />
          </button>
        </li>
        <li class="todos__item todo-style" draggable="true">
          <button
            class="todos__complete btn"
            aria-label="complete todo"
          ></button>
          <p class="todos__text">
            Mark as complete by pressing the left circle
          </p>
          <button class="todos__delete" aria-label="delete todo">
            <img
              class="todos__delete__img"
              src="assets/icon-cross.svg"
              alt="an icon with the symbol x that will allow you to delete the selected todo "
            />
          </button>
        </li>
        <li class="todos__item todo-style" draggable="true">
          <button
            class="todos__complete btn"
            aria-label="complete todo"
          ></button>
          <p class="todos__text">
            Or delete a todo by pressing the right X mark
          </p>
          <button class="todos__delete" aria-label="delete todo">
            <img
              class="todos__delete__img"
              src="assets/icon-cross.svg"
              alt="an icon with the symbol x that will allow you to delete the selected todo "
            />
          </button>
        </li>
        <li class="todos__item todo-style" draggable="true">
          <button
            class="todos__complete btn"
            aria-label="complete todo"
          ></button>
          <p class="todos__text">
            You can filter 'All', 'Active' and 'Completed' todos below
          </p>
          <button class="todos__delete" aria-label="delete todo">
            <img
              class="todos__delete__img"
              src="assets/icon-cross.svg"
              alt="an icon with the symbol x that will allow you to delete the selected todo "
            />
          </button>
        </li>
        <li class="todos__item todo-style" draggable="true">
          <button
            class="todos__complete btn"
            aria-label="complete todo"
          ></button>
          <p class="todos__text">Search for todos by typing in the box above</p>
          <button class="todos__delete" aria-label="delete todo">
            <img
              class="todos__delete__img"
              src="assets/icon-cross.svg"
              alt="an icon with the symbol x that will allow you to delete the selected todo "
            />
          </button>
        </li>
        <li class="todos__item todo-style" draggable="true">
          <button
            class="todos__complete btn"
            aria-label="complete todo"
          ></button>
          <p class="todos__text">
            Toggle between light and dark mode, by pressing the sun/moon icon
            above
          </p>
          <button class="todos__delete" aria-label="delete todo">
            <img
              class="todos__delete__img"
              src="assets/icon-cross.svg"
              alt="an icon with the symbol x that will allow you to delete the selected todo "
            />
          </button>
        </li>
        <li class="todos__item todo-style" draggable="true">
          <button
            class="todos__complete btn"
            aria-label="complete todo"
          ></button>
          <p class="todos__text">
            Drag and drop todo items, to re-position them
          </p>
          <button class="todos__delete" aria-label="delete todo">
            <img
              class="todos__delete__img"
              src="assets/icon-cross.svg"
              alt="an icon with the symbol x that will allow you to delete the selected todo "
            />
          </button>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

```
draggables.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("dragstart", () => {
    item.classList.add("dragging");
  });
  item.addEventListener("dragend", () => {
    item.classList.remove("dragging");
  });
});

todoList.addEventListener("dragover", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const afterElement = positionDraggableElement(todoList, e.clientY);
  const draggable = document.querySelector(".dragging");
  if (afterElement == null) {
    todoList.appendChild(draggable);
  } else {
    todoList.insertBefore(draggable, afterElement);
  }
});

function positionDraggableElement(todoList, y) {
  const draggableItems = [
    ...todoList.querySelectorAll(".todos__item:not(.dragging)"),
  ];

  return draggableItems.reduce(
    (closest, item) => {
      const box = item.getBoundingClientRect();
      const offset = y - box.top - box.height / 2;
      if (offset < 0 && offset > closest.offset) {
        return { offset: offset, element: item };
      } else {
        return closest;
      }
    },
    { offset: Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY }
  ).element;
}
```

Repo: https://github.com/DanK1368/todo__app

Live Site: https://dank1368.github.io/todo__app/

Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

since you do

```
todoList.innerHTML += html;
```

when you add a todo, those event listeners that add/remove `dragging` class are no longer attached to - you'll need to re-run

```
draggables.forEach((item) => {
```

but this would not include the added todo

So, I would suggest a function like

```
function initTodoDragging()
  document.querySelectorAll(".todos__item").forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener("dragstart", () => {
      item.classList.add("dragging");
    });
    item.addEventListener("dragend", () => {
      item.classList.remove("dragging");
    });
  });
}
```

Call that on load - in place of the inline code that uses `draggables` ... and also call that after

```
todoList.innerHTML += html;
```

---

A better solution, in my opinion, is

```
// remove this as it's no longer needed
// const draggables = document.querySelectorAll(".todos__item");
// .....
// ..... SNIP .....
// .....
//template for new todo
const todoTemplate = (todo) => {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.draggable = true;
    li.classList.add("todos__item", "todo-style");
    li.innerHTML = `
    <button class="todos__complete btn"></button>
    <p class="todos__text">${todo}</p>
    <button class="todos__delete">
        <img
            class="todos__delete__img"
            src="assets/icon-cross.svg"
            alt="an icon with the symbol x that will allow you to delete the selected todo "
        />
    </button>`;
    initTodoDragging(li); // add the dragstart/end handlers
    todoList.appendChild(li);
};
// .....
// ..... SNIP .....
// .....
//draggable todo feature
function initTodoDragging(item) {
    item.addEventListener("dragstart", () => {
        item.classList.add("dragging");
    });
    item.addEventListener("dragend", () => {
        item.classList.remove("dragging");
    });
}
document.querySelectorAll(".todos__item").forEach(initTodoDragging);
```

Comment: Thanks, i see the issue now. I thought the event listeners are already added to the new todos being created. Will make the changes and see if i get it to work.

Comment: @DanielKoett `I thought the event listeners are already added to the new todos` - the "new todos", as far as the dragstart/stop events, being **all of them**, not just the added one, after `todoList.innerHTML += html;`

Comment: it worked perfectly. Your solution makes sense. Thanks